# What would be passed for numsplits in getsplits()

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

My understanding on **`getSplits()`** is, `FileInputformat` class implements `Inputformat` interface, which has a `getSplits()` method which is responsible for calculating the split size and the file length. `getSplits()` has a parameter `numSplits`. What would be passed to that by default? I tried searching but no luck. I am assuming if `isSplittable()` is false then `0` would be passed else some other. But could someone help me in knowing how the value is passed and the relevant portion of the code.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to share my understandings on this.

The `getSplits(JobConf job, int numSplits)` method of `FileInputFormat` class is from the **old API** of mapreduce. Here the numSplits is given just as a hint where in the actual calculation of the splits also depends on few other default and user configuration. Mostly this argument is not required in the InputSplit calculation, can be useful only when the user wants to override. Please refer,

http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/FileInputFormat.html

The `numSplits` argument is populated by the `JobClient` class ,default is 1 , where the value is `job.getNumMapTasks()` , and it calls the getSplits method on FileInputFormat class.Please refer,

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/com.cloudera.hadoop/hadoop-core/0.20.2-737/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobClient.java

The `isSplittable()` method doesn't have any role in deciding the value of `numSplits` argument, all it is about a boolean value used in the FileInputFormat class.

As per the new mapreduce API the `numSplits` argument is no longer required in the `FileInputFormat` class.Please refer,

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.2.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/FileInputFormat.html

Hope this helps..

Comment: @Vignesh, were you able to figure out the idea?.